# How can I make a distinction between shared and user mailboxes in PowerAutomate?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I want to check in a flow whether an internal mail address is a shared or user mailbox. Depending on this, I would branch off whether a mail is sent from a shared or user mailbox (PowerAutomate has two events for sending mails, one for shared and one for a normal user mailbox). Is this possible and how?

Answer (score -1):

Similar to **power automate** , logic app has outlook office 365 connector supports both sending an email from shared or user mail boxes by using the below actions.

[image]

Comment: that wasn't my question. my question is how can I check if an e-mail adress is a shared or user mailbox